# Looping error when opening Facebook-app login-window on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, loops, authentication

I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK and API to log users into my website, and it all works peachy aside from a looping console error.

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php? Domains, protocols and ports must match.

It only displays when the FaceBook login dialog box is displayed and stops when it closes, but it's an annoyance that I'd rather be rid of.

## Facebook SDK

### scripts/facebook.js

```
//FB SDK (Software Development Kit) for easy access to FB commands @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
window.onload = function(){
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '350562728295861', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'http:url', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };
}
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

## Login Button

### scripts/facebook.js

```
function logIn(){
    FB.login(function(){ //calls the Facebook popup window

    });
}
```

## The Channel File

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

The scripts are located in root/scripts and the channel and index files are found in the root folder.

I've written a lot more, but this is effectively just the SDK itself and it still throws the error. So I'm expecting some sort of missing value or other oversight.